# pow(-0.857487, 1.5) returns NaN - Alternatives?

Tags: c++, nan, pow

in C++, when I try `pow(-0.857487, 1.5)` it returns nan. I found out this is due to an overflow.

Is there any alternative to math.pow() or any other way to calculate this value?

Comment: That's NaN and fine. It's like division by zero. What result did you expect? :)

Comment: That's pure math, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents and move along.. erm, I mean, check those -0.8 and 1.5 params, it's highly probable that one of them is wrong (out of your model's domain)

Comment: Maybe you meant to use the `std::abs(.)` for the first argument?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem at hand is not any kind of overflow, but that the result of `pow(-0.857487, 1.5) = -0.857487 ^ 3/2 = sqrt(-0.857487)^3 = -0.794038... i` (simplified demonstration math) is not a real number.

In general, `pow(a,b)` does not exist in the real numbers for negative `a` and non-integer `b`. For positive `a` however, `pow(a,b)` always exists and is real, so if you work with real numbers only, you probably want something like `pow(abs(a),b)`.

If complex arithmetic is actually what you want, you can use `std::complex`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main () {
    std::complex<double> d = -0.857487;
    std::cout << std::pow(d, 1.5);
}
```

Output: `(-1.45862e-16,-0.794038)`. See it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/997b80cb3d9a4439).

Comment: oh okay thanks ... I was not aware of that! I'm working with real numbers.

Comment: Though this is otherwise a good answer, I strongly oppose to equating `sqrt(-x) = i * sqrt(x)`. [I'm not alone in this.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/144404/44190)

Comment: @Rhymoid Yeah, I simplified for programmers. I added a remark, but the point stands.

Answer (score 0):

[Baum mit Augen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33786983/3982001) is excellent, I would just like to add that there is a sort of dirty trick to have the maths work.

The problem is that you want to raise a negative number to the `1.5`<sup>th</sup> power, that is `3/2`, and the negative sign will be kept when raising to the `3`<sup>rd</sup> power, and then you have a square root of a negative number which is not real. A "workaround" is that you can write `1.5` not as `3/2` but as `6/4`. This way the exponent `6` is even (unlike `3`) and it will make your number positive, and then the root is real. This is, however, equivalent to making your number positive before you try to raise it to `1.5`.

It might, or it might not, be useful. As I said, this is a dirty trick, and one of the reasons that this operation (non-integer power of a negative number) is not even defined.

Comment: That's a rather roundabout was to get `pow(abs(a),b)`.  If you want `pow(abs(a),b)` then code it in the more obvious way.  If you want `pow(a,b)` and not `pow(abs(a),b)` don't use tricks to pretend some wrong answer is right.

Comment: @JSF Agreed, I would certainly go for `pow(abs(a),b)` if I had to code this. I was not so much focusing on the code, but rather on the concept that such an operation is not defined because `3/2` and `6/4` should be the same number, but using the former or the latter leads to completely different results.

Comment: I think 3/2 and 6/4 are the same for this.  `pow(x,3./2)` and `pow(x,6./4)` are the same and in algebra (but not exactly in floating point) `pow(pow(x,1./4),6)` is still the same (similar point to the earlier answer).  But you are implying `pow(pow(x,6),1./4)` should also be the same and that goes too far.